# How to extract specific part of html using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to extract the what's within the 'title' tag from the following html, but so far I didn't manage to.

```
<div class="pull_right date details" title="22.12.2022 01:49:03 UTC-03:00">
```

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("messages.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'pull_right date details'})

print(results)
```

And the output is a list with all <div for the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the value inside `title`. Simply call `['title']`.

If you use `find_all`, then this will return a list. Therefore you will need an index (e.g `[0]['title']`)

**For example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fp = '<html><div class="pull_right date details" title="22.12.2022 01:49:03 UTC-03:00"></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'pull_right date details'})

print(results[0]['title'])
```

Or:

```
results = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'pull_right date details'})

print(results['title'])
```

**Output:**

```
22.12.2022 01:49:03 UTC-03:00
22.12.2022 01:49:03 UTC-03:00
```

Comment: Trying both suggestions, the output is just one instance, and within the html there are more than 100.

Comment: Can you please include sample html in your question?

Comment: No need to, I used a for loop and got all instances. Thanks!!!